# Как грамотно реализовать Single Activity Architecture?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, архитектура, kotlin

Подскажите пожалуйста: Есть небольшое корпоративное приложение, с семью вкладками в навигационном меню. Каждая вкладка это отдельное активити, с применением MVP (для каждого активити есть свой presenter  и интерфейс с контрактами). Почитав статьи, понял что иметь много активити в приложении не есть хорошо.

Есть ли какие-либо устоявшиеся способы реализации Single Activity Architecture, которые уже себя зарекомендовали. Или примеры с конкретной реализацией. И как правильно туда внедрить MVP, т.е. я так понимаю для фрагмента, где нужно взаимодействие с сервером нужно писать отдельный presenter?
Есть ли минусы в применении подобной архитектуры? На какие грабли придётся наступать? И как грамотно организовать управление стеком фрагментов? (очень много вопросов)))

Буду благодарен за развернутый ответ или ссылки на полезные материалы!

Comment: То что сейчас изучаю и я: https://developer.android.com/jetpack, стоит начать с этого, а это именно то что вам нужно: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation.html, ну по крайней мере на моё мнение

Comment: `Multi Activity` так же нормально как и `Single Activity`. Последнее сейчас пропагандируется в связи с появлением `Navigation Component`, но это не значит что первое уже плохо. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation

Comment: В чем плохость множества активити ? Формально перейдя на идею Single Activity Architecture, активити сменятся фрагментами - функциональность экранов останется той же, поменяется способ переключения - вместо переключения между активити будет переключение между фрагментами. Кроме освоения новой идеи, ее реализации/применения пользы никакой.

Comment: Что касается MVP, то все останется точно также - презентеры будут привязаны к фрагментам, вместо активити. Презентер, в общем виде (по-моему), должен получать команды из UI (от действий пользователя), передавать их другому объекту - бизнес-логика, та в свою очередь передает запрос на получение данных в дата-слой, который может создавать запросы, которые понимает сервер, получать ответы от сервера, транформировать их в тот вид, который понимает бизнес-логика.

Comment: Бизнес-логика же, в свою очередь, решает что делать с полученными данными, и например, говорит презентеру - покажи вот такие данные, а презентер, используя вью (интерфейс от активити/фрагмента) - передает готовые данные во вью, которая что-то показывает в UI.

Comment: Собственно, будет полезно почитать [Clean architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) от Дядюшки Боба